# ошибка OverflowError: int too large to convert to float

Tags: python

```
import math
def tailor(x):
   n = 1
   s=0
   l=3*x
   while (abs(((1+2**n)*x**n)/n) >= 10**(-6)):
      s += ((-1)**(n-1))*((1+2**n)*x**n)/n
      n += 1
      if (abs(((1+2**n)*x**n)/n) > l):
         exit (2)
   return s
x = float(input("Введите координаты x:"))
print(tailor(x), math.log(1+3*x+2*x**2))
```

ошибка возникает при х=0.5;  код находит значения по ряду тейлора для функции натурального логарифма

Answer (score 1):

Одна из проблем с этим кодом заключается в том, что он всегда начинает серию с n = 1, даже если значение x не равно 1. Это означает, что ряд не будет точным для значений x, которые не равны 1. Кроме того, в коде используется другая формула для разложения функции натурального логарифма в ряд Тейлора, что может привести к иным результатам.

Другая проблема с этим кодом заключается в том, что он использует жестко заданное значение для максимального числа итераций (l=3*x). Это означает, что код перестанет выполняться после определенного количества итераций, даже если ряд еще не сошелся до удовлетворительного уровня точности. Это может привести к тому, что код вернет неполный или неверный результат.

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что вы используете функцию exit() в середине цикла while. Функция exit() приводит к немедленному завершению программы, что означает, что цикл while никогда не будет продолжаться после того момента, когда вызывается exit().

Чтобы исправить это, вы могли бы просто удалить вызов exit() или заменить его оператором break, что приведет к немедленному завершению цикла while.

Кроме того, вам следует рассмотреть возможность использования цикла for вместо цикла while. Это сделало бы код более читаемым и понятным. Вы могли бы переписать функцию следующим образом:

```
def tailor(x):
    s = 0
    l = 3 * x
    for n in range(1, 100):
        term = ((-1)**(n-1))*((1+2**n)*x**n)/n
        if abs(term) < 10**(-6):
            break
        if abs(term) > l:
            exit(2)
        s += term
    return s
```

Эта версия функции использует цикл for для перебора членов ряда Тейлора. Цикл будет продолжаться до тех пор, пока значение текущего термина не станет меньше 10 ^(-6), после чего оператор break приведет к завершению цикла. Если значение текущего термина больше l, то программа завершит работу с кодом возврата 2. Эта версия функции более удобочитаема и понятна, чем ваша версия.